# Using LINQ I have a list of lists, how do I select all objects that exist in every list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of lists:

```
List<Tuple<string, List<SomeObject>>
```

I want to select all `SomeObjects` that exist in all rows of the list above.

Some will just exist in one or two lists, but I want all objects that exist in every single list, with other objects discarded.

I can't figure out an elegant solution to this without a bunch of c# code. Is there a nice way?

Comment: Have you tried LINQ `.SelectMany`?

Comment: what @danludwig said, beat me by a second

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list.Select (x => x.Item2 as IEnumerable<SomeObject>)
    .Aggregate((x,y)=> x.Intersect(y))
    .ToList();
```

Or, as Jeppe Stig Nielsen suggested (and I think it's much more elegant):

```
list.Select(x => x.Item2.AsEnumerable())
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: No need for `as IEnumerable<SomeObject>`

Comment: If you're using mono, you need it.

Comment: Really?!! Why's that though? If `Intersect` is defined for `IEnumerable<T>` it should also be defined for `List<T>`...

Comment: You need it also without mono in .NET 4.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why's that?

Comment: I think because there isn't really a List<T>.Intersect. It is defined in Enumerable class, and it returns an IEnumerable<T>, not a List<T>. And this overload of Aggregate needs that both arguments and the return to be of same type. Somehow the return being an IEnumerable<T> isn't enough for the type inference to know that both arguments must be IEnumerable<T> also.

Comment: Your solution can also be written `list.Select(x => x.Item2.AsEnumerable()).Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect).ToList();`, of course.

Comment: The relevant overload of `Aggregate<>` has just one type parameter `TSource`. You need `TSource` to be `IEnumerable<SomeObject>`, not `List<SomeObject>`. So the inclusion of "as enumerable" helps with that. An alternative is to give the type argument explicitly, of course. Just to emphasize that it is possible to use `TSource == List<SomeObject>`, this also works: `list.Select(x => x.Item2).Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y).ToList());` (don't use, creates new `List<>` instance for each iteration).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand correctly, You need intersection of many lists:

```
var results = source.First().Item2
foreach (var element in source.Skip(1) )
{
    results = results.Intersect(element.Item2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strongly inspired by Juan Lopes's beautiful answer, you can define this extension:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectMany<TSource>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> sources)
{
  return sources.Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect);
}
```

then this works:

```
var result = list.Select(x => x.Item2).IntersectMany();
```

It works because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant in `T` (C# 4, .NET 4.0).

Answer (score -1):

Presuming that the class overrides `Equals` + `GetHashCode` or you have a custom `IEqualityComparer<SomeObject>` you can use following query which uses `Enumerable.All`:

```
var result = list
    .SelectMany(t => t.Item2)   // select all objects
    .Distinct()                 // just an optimization since duplicates are guaranteed
    .Where(obj => list.All(t => t.Item2.Contains(obj)));
```

Here's my sample data:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, List<SomeObject>>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create("a", new List<SomeObject> { new SomeObject { ID = 1 }, new SomeObject { ID = 2 }, new SomeObject { ID = 4 } }));
list.Add(Tuple.Create("b", new List<SomeObject> { new SomeObject { ID = 1 }, new SomeObject { ID = 2 }, new SomeObject { ID = 3 } }));
list.Add(Tuple.Create("c", new List<SomeObject> { new SomeObject { ID = 1 }, new SomeObject { ID = 2 }, new SomeObject { ID = 3 } }));
list.Add(Tuple.Create("d", new List<SomeObject> { new SomeObject { ID = 1 }, new SomeObject { ID = 2 }, new SomeObject { ID = 3 } }));
```

Only the `SomeObjects` with ID = 1 or ID = 2 are in all lists and that's the result of the query.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote or just boredom? It's not the most efficient or shortest way but it's straight-forward translation of this requirement, isn't it?